# Tabular: Using tabular to separate figures in a minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, minipage

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}                                                        
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{.5em}}c}
    \includegraphics[width = 2.5in]{something}
    \captionof{figure}[short]{figure 1}
    \label{one} &
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}[short]{figure 2}
    \label{two}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption[short]{figures}
  \label{three}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I want to put a `eps` file and a `TikZ` picture side by side as `subfigures` in a a `minipage`, but no matter what I try this doesn't work.  I also tried including the `TikZ` picture with `\includestandalone` but that failed as well.  How can I do this?

---

Gonzalo Medina

One question, how can I avoid the captions running to close and looking sloppy?

[image]

Comment: You need to convert `something.eps` to `something.pdf` first (using [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf)). The EPS (Postscript) and PDF formats can't be mixed together...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \hfill\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 2in]{something}
    \captionof{subfigure}[short]{A subfigure with a long caption spanning several lines}
    \label{one}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{subfigure}[short]{Another subfigure with a long caption spanning several lines}
    \label{two}
    \end{minipage}
  \captionof{figure}{A \LaTeX\ figure with two subfigures}
  \label{three}
\end{minipage}\hfill\null

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer worked great.  However, I have two questions.  What can I do if the captions of the subfigures are too long (see edit to post for a visual)?  To add `LaTeX` in the `\captionof`, I need `\pdftostring` (something syntactic like that)?

Comment: @dustin 1) You can reduce the width of the inner `minipage`s and use `\hfill` to center the subfigures (see my updated answer). 2) No; normally you don't need anything special to use `\LaTeX` inside a caption; in my updated answer I used `\LaTeX` inside `\captionof` without problems.